# Do not want to display some tabs on user page

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

I do not want to display some of the tabs that are on user page on some of the domain but the primary domain will have it.

How can I hide the tabs?(dont want to use css)

ex

```
$items['user/%/messages'] = array(
'title' => 'Messages',
'page callback'    => 'drupal_get_form',
'page arguments'   => array('privatemsg_list', 'list', 1),
'access callback'  => 'privatemsg_user_access',
'access arguments' => array('read all private messages'),
'type' => MENU_LOCAL_TASK,
```

);

I do not want to display the Messages tab on my secondary domain..(using drupal domain module)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this and check base url for domain

```
global $base_url;

    if($base_url=='youdomain'){
    $items['user/%/messages']['access callback'] = FALSE;
    }
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: well, i tried hook_menu_alter and the messages tabs disappeared as expected but then it disappeared in my primary domain too after building the menus.

Answer (score 0):

If it is just a matter of display without CSS I would use "[hook_menu_local_tasks_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_menu_local_tasks_alter/7)" and do something like :

```
function yourmodule_menu_local_tasks_alter(&$data, $router_item, $root_path) {
  global $base_root;
  if($root_path=='user/%/messages' && $base_root=='http://yourdomain.com' ) {
    foreach($data['tabs'][0]['output'] as $k => $item) {
      if($item['#link']['path']=='user/%/messages') {
        unset($data['tabs'][0]['output'][$k]);
        break;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: hook_menu_local_tasks_alter() is not available in drupal 6